# How to pause and resume SpeechRecognizer in Android?

Tags: android, voice-recognition

I am using SpeechRecognizer class.

Here is my code:

```
SpeechRecognizer     speechRecognizer;
speechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(getBaseContext());
MyRecognitionListener speechListner=new MyRecognitionListener();
speechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(speechListner);
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, getApplication().getPackageName());
speechRecognizer.startListening(intent);
```

The problem is that I could not pause and resume it. I already tried:

```
speechRecognizer.cancel();
speechRecognizer.stopListening();
```

But it still listen.

Comment: Did you try calling stopListening() before cancel? You cannot call stopListening() to a cancelled speechrecognizer.

Comment: It also matters where you are calling these functions. It could be a nice idea to see your RecognitionListener class.

Comment: @babatenor After calling stopListening() before cancel(), it works now.
Thank you!

Comment: @babatenor Could you make the answer for this question, then I will accept it.

Comment: There you go. You are welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot call stopListening() to a cancelled SpeechRecognizer. Call it before the cancel().

```
speechRecognizer.stopListening();
speechRecognizer.cancel();
```